# Matching Specific Words in String SQL

Tags: sql

I am making a cocktail recipe app. My first table (Ingredients) first is formatted as:

```
 Recipe Name     Spirits     Syrup                Juice                 Fruit
 Kiwi Martini    60ml gin    15ml sugar syrup     1tsp lemon juice      1 kiwi
```

The second table (UserIngredients) is formatted as:

```
 UserID    Ingredient
 1         gin
 1         sugar syrup
 1         lemon juice
 1         kiwi
```

It would be pointless to have my user enter exact liquid amounts (like 60ml gin) to get a match so I was wondering if there was any way to write a query to return "Kiwi Martini" that would consider "gin" and "60ml gin", "sugar syrup" and "15ml sugar syrup"...etc. matches.

All of my datatypes are varchar.

Thank you!

Comment: Your "ingredients" table doesn't seem particularly useful.  What if the cocktail has more than one "spirit" or "juice" -- as many do.  You should fix the data model.

Comment: I am using a website with very simple recipes for my data input. None of the cocktails listed have more than one of each ingredient.